# Class with public properties as list of structures for saving a communcation protocol

Tags: vb.net

I want to save a communication inside a class. After that I plan to serialize the class o a XML file, where all datapoints are decoded between a tag.

Therefore I want to explain my communication protocol first.

The message Frame Looks like the following

LIE01
LIE02

When the communication ends, I have around 3000 of this telegrams inside a raw variable.

Here I describe the Messages:

- LIE01: Header + 1 data word
- LIE02: Header + 2 data words

My idea was to decode the frame and save it in a list (or array) of structures that are public properties of my class.

```vb
Public Class Com
    Public Structure sLIE01
        Public Property Header As Int16
        Public Property data1 As Int16
    End Structure

    Public Structure sLIE02
        Public Property Header As Int16
        Public Property data1 As Int16
        Public Property data2 As Int16
    End Structure

    Public Property LIE01 As List(Of sLIE01)
        Get
            ?
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of sLIE01))
            ?
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property LIE02 As List(Of sLIE02)
        Get
            ?
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of sLIE02))
            ?
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Unfortunatelly I am more a beginner than an expert, so that I have no idea, how to write the code to `Set` or `Get` a specific LIE message.

Even I'm not sure, whether my way is a common way for this purpose or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still want to use Get Set it would look like this...

```
Private _LIE01 As List(Of sLIE01)
Public Property LIE01 As List(Of sLIE01)
    Get
        Return _LIE01
    End Get
    Set(value as List(Of sLIE01))
        _LIE01 = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use auto implemented properties in your code and skip getters and setters altogether (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/auto-implemented-properties). You'll then be able to assign lists to them like:

```
Dim newList as new List(of sLIE01)()
ComInstance.Lie01 = newList
```

You can also operate on those list properties directly (just make sure you initialize them in class constructor to avoid NullReferenceException):

```
Dim lie as sLie01
ComInstance.Lie01.Add(lie)
```

Also consider replacing structures with classes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/structures-and-classes